# How to send fetched data in Splash Screen Activity to other activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Fetched data is a JSON string list of Users. Let's say it has 5 string-value property and it would be less than 30 user. I thought that i could just put it in Intent, but:

1. Is it really the best way to do it?
2. What if there is hundreds of user, what is the best way?

FYI i'm using [Fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel) to fetch data and it could request asynchronously.

Comment: See https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#5

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ty for your tips, but aren't two activity couldn't have same instance of ViewModel?

Comment: @rifqimf127 you can use a same viewmodel for several activites by using sharedViewModel. https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-android/viewmodel?id=shared-viewmodel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your question, you are fetching the data on the Splash Screen (Activity). Also, you confirm that the data can be fetched asynchronously.

I would suggest, that instead of fetching the data on Splash Screen, fetch the data directly in the activity where the data is required.

However, there could be several ways of storing the data instead of using Intent to pass data between activities. Some of the ways are as below:

1. Database (Room) - These are used to store data and query accordingly. You can save data in multiple tables too based on your requirements.
2. SharedPreferences - Best used to store frequently accessed data. This too can be used to save JSON Response.
3. File Storage - You can also save the data to a file for access.

You can read about storing data in Android in detail to better select a way to save and pass data.

Comment: thanks for answer, i'd already fetch it directly in activity whom required it, but the problem is it take 3-5 second to fetch it, that's why i tried to fetch in splash screen. are all the 3 ways you mention store it persistently? the data might be change a lot so i don't know how to sync it.

Comment: Yes. Data stored is persistent, until and unless being tampered. However, there are always advantages and disadvantages associated with each of these methods. If you are sure that the data is updated quite frequently, I would suggest you use DB as a storage medium. Also, implement a function on your server and app that updates only the modified data, rather than downloading whole data again every time. You can also read about caching and syncing data between the app and the server.